# What is the difference between owl:equivalentClass and rdfs;subClassOf when making owl:Restrictions

Tags: computer-science, owl, ontology, semantic-web, rdfs

I need to create theset that is restricted to items that are only delivered to Italy.

I don't fully understand the difference between `owl:equivalentClass` and `rdfs:subClassOf` in the context of my problem.

```
:deliversToItaly owl:equivalentClass [a owl:restriction; 
                                      owl:ownProperty ebay:shipsTo;
                                      owl:allValuesFrom geo:Italy].
```

vs.

```
:deliversToItaly rdfs:subClassOf [a owl:restriction; 
                                  owl:ownProperty ebay:shipsTo;
                                  owl:allValuesFrom geo:Italy].
```

Could someone explain the difference between the two, and possibly explain it in context between the two examples I have provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically, you are defining the class as Primitive (subClassOf) versus Defined (equivalentClass). The main difference is in inferencing in one or both directions.

The Primitive class is single direction:

- any Thing with ShipsTo with values from Italy can be inferred to be a deliversToItaly
  The Defined class is both directions:
- as above, and
- any Thing that is a deliversToItay can be inferred to have shipTo with values from Italy

A Defined class is used when you are confident that you have necessary and sufficient rules for class membership - otherwise Primitive is used for necessary rules only.

Comment: To add to that: in the example given, if `owl:equivalentClass` is used, finding `:individual a [a owl:restriction; owl:ownProperty ebay:shipsTo; owl:allValuesFrom geo:Italy].` in the ontology enables `:individual a :deliversToItaly` to be inferred. if `rdfs:subClassOf` is used, the inference is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, Renato, that has helped me :)

Comment: Using the Defined (equivalentClass) version to model this matter, would it be an issue if there are instances that from type of :deliversToItaly but have not a relation ebay:shipsTo geo:Italy? Thus, just adding this triple (:indi, a, :deliversToItaly) would be OK or result in an error? Maybe @Ignazio can help?

Comment: You can explicitly assert that an individual is of type `:deliversToItaly` It will not cause any errors.